# Unchecked Cast warning in Java?

Tags: java

In this code I am making an implementation of a generic linkedlist in java.

```
public class LL<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
```

My Node class is defined like

```
private class Node{
private Item data;
private Node next;
public Node(Item data){
    this.data = data;
    next = null;
}
}
```

Now my doubt is, I keep getting warnings when coding

```
 Node x = head, y = (Node) b.head;
Type safety: Unchecked cast from LL.Node to LL<Item>.Node
```

Should I ignore this, why does the compiler generate that. And is there a workaround it ?

**EDIT :**

b is of type LL, the function signature looks like

```
public void mergeAlternate(LL b){
```

And head is a private instance variable of LL class

```
private Node head;
```

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: @TheNewIdiot He should understand **why** the warning occurs, not just blindly suppress it. If this was an answer it'd be an immediate -1 from me.

Comment: What is the type of `b` and `b.head`?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `b`?

Comment: @TomG I agree. hershey92, can you please post where the head is defined.

Comment: hershey92, we'd need to know what `head` is, what `b` is, how the `.head` method is declared...

Comment: @Tom G I missed that, actually "b" is of type LL("the linkedlist class")

Comment: I have made some edits, let me know if more clarifications is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a generic implementation then it should be generic internally as well.

You are missing the type parameter for your `Node` class. It should be generic like this:

```
private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;
    public Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

}
```

And where you are using that class you can do something like this:

`new Node<Item> // ...`

And your code will look like this:

```
Node<Item> x = head, y = b.head;
```

and you won't get warnings that way.

My spider sense however tells me that there is some architectural problem there. Since you did not show us all your code we can't help you any further.

Comment: `T extends Comparable<Item>`?

Comment: If you understand the code, looks like `Node` is an inner class inside `LL` class, to in order to make it work you should mark it as `static` and just have `Node<Item>`. Having this, you just have to declare `Node<Item> node;` variables with no problem.

Comment: It should not be `static` since he won't use it without an instance of `LL`. I used `T` instead of `Item`. I could've used `ITEM` as well but using `Item` for a type parameter name confuses it with an actual type name.

Comment: I can understand why you used `T`, but just note that OP already uses `Item`, so your solution must be adapted to current OP's code and you can suggest using `T` instead of `Item` for readability purposes. By the way, I still think it should be a `static` class since you could pass an array as constructor param to initialize the data for the linked list thus no need to have an instance of `LL` to start creating `Node` instances :) (of course, this is a design matter but not focused on the main problem, just an improvement).